# Nothing happens when i click google-chrome icon. I get "command not found" errors when i try launching google-chrome from the terminal

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, java

I changed my PATH environment variables when i was trying to install Java on my pc, then i tried restoring the old PATH by completely uninstalling java from my pc which caused google-chrome to stop working. I tried doing some exports in order to remedy the situation to no avail. Nothing happens when i click the google-chrome icon and i get the following errors when i try launching chrome from the terminal with `google-chrome` command

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 8: readlink: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 24: mkdir: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: exec: cat: not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: exec: cat: not found
```

The result of `echo $PATH` is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Please help. I use Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Your PATH is probably still messed up. Please add the output of echo $PATH to your original posting.

Comment: The result of echo $PATH is /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: The "/bin/usr/games" seems wrong. Should be /bin:/usr/games

Comment: The default PATH is from /etc/environment and user modifications are usually made in .profile.  Looks like your /etc/environment file may have the problem -- did you  change it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `bin` is not in your path, which is why `readlink`, `mkdir`, and `cat`, are not able to be found. The problem seems to be right there:

```
/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
```

I would first check to see if you have a directory `/bin/usr/games` and if you don't then change that part in your path to

```
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
```

If you do have that directory then just add this to the end of your path

```
:/bin
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Maximilian for your help. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @TendongzeGodson If my answer solved your problem could you "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you!